# How can i receive traffic with no content length and no EOF?

Tags: html, parsing

I'm working on an HTTP parser and was wondering how can i parse traffic that is sent with no content length and no EOF?

Answer (score 0):

Read the data until the connection is shutdown (from the other side).

This is how the original HTTP worked, but it's not very nice; if the server crashes, or you lose network connectivity in the middle of the transmission, you might not notice that the response is truncated.